# Find Each Instance - Return Column Header in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

[image]

How do I return the first time I emailed each customer by date? For example, I want B3 to read "20-May-13" C3 to read "02-Oct-15" and D3 to read "26-May-16".

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this formula in B3, then copy over and down:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($G$2:$K$2,AGGREGATE(15,6,(COLUMN($G3:$K3)-COLUMN($G3)+1)/($G3:$K3=1),COLUMN(A:A))),"")
```

[image]

---

If your column header is a true date then you can use this formula:

```
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,$G$2:$K$2/($G3:$K3=1),COLUMN(A:A)),"")
```

Comment: @Scott Craner thanks! But I keep getting "41332" come up - even though I adjusted the formula to my spreadsheet? http://imgur.com/c6vsUwK

Comment: @Christian you need to format the cells as a date.  Right now it is formatted as "General" and it is showing the numeric value of the date.  So format them the way you want.

Comment: @Scott Craner - Thank you so much!

Comment: @Christian please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.  It is something only you can do.